# How to count and extract arguments from a nested parentheses math function?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to write some code to extract arguments from a nested parentheses math function of type string, for example: `equation = "f(a,b,g(a,b,c))"`.
I want to count how many arguments are in this function and extract from it like this:

- arguments_list = ["a","b","g(a,b,c)"], and arguments = 3. I tried this to extract string from the first inner bracket and I want to store them in an array so I can count the length as number of arguments:

```
equation = "f(a,b,g(a,b,c))"
inner_bracket = ""
start_index = equation.index("(")
end_index = equation.rfind(")")
inner_bracket = equation[start_index+1:end_index]
print(inner_bracket) #Output:a,b,g(a,b,c)
```

But I encounter difficulties in storing g(a,b,c) as a whole, Can I have some suggestions on how to achieve it? Thank you!

Comment: The usual approach is to write a parser which builds a tree. Writing a proper parser is a moderately challenging topic but extremely well covered by existing questions and the literature.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you! I will try to look into parse tree implementation for this question.